# How often can self-storage raise rent on existing contracts in NY?

Tags: new-york-state, rent

If a self-storage company has an existing customer who has had a contract for a few months, and they want to increase the rent, how frequently can the rent actually be increased?

Thanks

Comment: What does the contract say?

Comment: My guess is that they can raise it as often as they want -- you can always take your things elsewhere.  There are probably some conditions imposed by the state concerning notice periods and similar things.  In my experience, most places give a teaser rate for some time -- I recently moved some stuff across the hall into a larger unit and my monthly rent decreased.  It will of course eventually be higher than the old rent.